# How to get MQ CLI commands to run against a single MQ installation?

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a 2 installations of MQ on my machine. Installation1 and Installation2.
 I have not set the default installation using `setmqinst` but when i run the `dspmq` command i get a list of queue managers from both the installations.
I have qualified the dspmq command with the full path. i.e. `/opt/mqm/bin/dspmq`, even with this the list contains all the queue managers from both the installations.
**How do I run these commands only against only one of the installations?** Is it by setting and changing the default installation using `setmqinst`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dspmq` command is documented in the IBM MQ Knowledge center [dspmq](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083180_.htm) page.

If you add `-o installation` to the dspmq command it with show the installation name along with the queue manager name, but will always show all queue mangers on the server.

You can grep the installation name to limit the output to one of the two installations, for example:

**Installation1:** `dspmq -o installation|grep Installation1`

**Installation2:** `dspmq -o installation|grep Installation2`

Comment: @Ajay, if you found this answer or any answer helpful please accept the best answer, to accept a answer you click the grayed out check mark that is below the down vote arrow on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To run commands against a specific installation, it is best to first set up the environment for that installation by using the setmqenv command:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083560_.htm

But even after that, dspmq will show all QMs on that server I think.